# How to use Response.Buffer and Flush

Tags: asp-classic

I've an asp page that has to check are large database, takes about 4 seconds

I'm trying to use Response.Buffer to show a "Please Wait" then display the result of the database search. Then remove the "Please Wait"

No matter where a place the Buffer = True and Flush I just get a blank page until the result is displayed.

Here's the latest attempt:

```
<% Response.Buffer = True 'Top of page' %>
<html>
Please Wait....
<% Database search %>
<% Remove please wait %>
<% Response.Flush %>
Display results
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

John

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I've got there

Response.Flush straight after the "Please Wait"

Comment: The page is buffered until you issue the Response.Flush() command. So just after the "please wait..." and before the time-consuming operation would be the right spot.